# .net core 3.1 image upload help me pls

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I cannot upload images in .net core 3.1. I can save them as text in the database, but I cannot do anything in the image file in the project.

I tried to do it from here but I couldn't do it because of the file used with viewmodel and interface. Can I do it without using interface and viewmodel.

https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/05/upload-multiple-files-in-aspnet-core-mvc.html

Comment: Hi Harun, welcome to StackOverflow. When asking questions, please take note that it does not hurt to take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what is your code 
.But I can give you an example from my own code

try this way. In cshtml file must be as below:

```
<form asp-action="AddBlog" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Image</label>
                <input id="blogImage" asp-for="UploadedImage" type="file" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="add" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And your action method must be as below:

```
    [HttpPost] 
    public IActionResult AddBlog(BlogAddOrEditDTO blog)
    { 

         //some code logic
    }
```

And BlogAddOrEditDTO must be as below:

```
    public class BlogAddOrEditDTO  
    { 
        public IFormFile UploadedImage { get; set; }
    }
```

**This example it works for me in ASP.NET Core 3.1**

Comment: https://files.fm/u/nyrayvqw#/view/View.PNG view                                                            https://files.fm/u/nyrayvqw#/view/controller.PNG controller                                               https://files.fm/u/nyrayvqw#/view/repository+1.PNG repository                                                 https://files.fm/u/nyrayvqw#/view/repo2.PNG repository mapper                                              my code is like this

Comment: public int ImageId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Image { get; set; }
        [InverseProperty("Image")]
        public virtual ICollection<Article> Article { get; set; }                                               MODEL

Comment: @Harun please add these attirbute to form tag  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" and try again

Comment: add them, obj appears in the controller as null

Comment: Please check the code which  I wrote at my answer @Harun

Comment: thank you I did but I can't show pictures in view @Ramil Aliyev                                             code : <td>
                    <img src="~/Image/@item.Image"style="max-width: 500px;">
               
                <td>

Comment: please check image source which you saved  your computer or server . What is value of item.Image ? I thinks value of ~/Image/@item.Image is incorrect